# gesture recognizer doubts in iphone

Tags: iphone

I know handling gestures in ios,but is it possible to implement DoubleTapGesture for a action?
that means

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeGesture:)];
    swipeGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight; // or whatever
    [table addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture];
    [swipeGesture release];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureleft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeGestureleft:)];
    swipeGestureleft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft; // or whatever
    [table addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureleft];
    [swipeGestureleft release];
```

we can do right and left swipe by this way,but i want DoubleTap gesture to do a action like the above code.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure UITapGestureRecognizer for that:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *dblTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
dblTap. numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
[table addGestureRecognizer:dblTap];
[dblTap release];
```

Comment: great it works,and one more doubt,can i implement sipeRightHold for an action?that is swipe to right then hold for another action?thanks .

Comment: It is not clear what you want... Check http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html docs, may be UILongPressGestureRecognizer is what you need?..